# How to make DrRacket give me exact numbers as fractions and not decimals?

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

I'm currently working with the beginning student language in DrRacket while reading through a book called "How to design programs". Currently if I type something like (/ 1 2) I get 0.5 as the answer, but the book seems to imply that there's an option to make it so that I get 1/2 as the answer, but I can't find the option anywhere. Does that option actually exist? How can I get my answers as fractions and not decimals?

I tried looking up for the option everywhere in DrRacket but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the menubar: Language > Choose Languages.

There will be a dialog. You should already have "Beginning Student" in "Teaching Languages" already highlighted/checked. So don't touch those if they are already correct.

Click "Show Details". This will make the dialog larger. On the right area (that just got expanded), choose "Mixed fractions" under "Fraction Style".

Click OK, and re-run your program.